# Initialization Error expected a file cucumber to run a .jar

Tags: java, junit, jar, cucumber, executable-jar

I have an automation test that I use Cucumber, Junit and I can run with Java Application.

Runner Class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = false, features = "src/main/java/FaixaVS_NaoCadastrado/FaixaVS_NaoCadastrado/FaixaVS_NaoCadastrado.feature", glue = { "StepDefinition" }, format = { "pretty",
"json:C:/Automação Receba Em Casa/Evidências/FVS_NaoCadastrado/Relatório/cucumber.json" }, tags = { "~@ignore" })

public class Runner {
}
```

Jar Class:

```
public class Jar {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Runner.class);
            for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
                System.out.println(failure.toString());
            }
        }
}
```

I can run it inside Eclipse as Java Application, but when I Export it like a Runnable jar and run it I receive the follow massage from CMD:

> C:\Users\c.guiao.de.oliveira>java -jar
>   C:\Users\c.guiao.de.oliveira\Desktop\FVS_NaoCadastrado.jar
>   initializationError(FaixaVS_NaoCadastrado.FaixaVS_NaoCadastrado.Runner):
>   Expected a file URL:rsrc:cucumber-java-1.2.3.jar

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

- Verify that the path you are using to get resource is correct. I
  encounter tests that IntelliJ (that is not case sensitive when it
  comes to resource path) executed successfully and `maven clean
  install` failed.
- Verify that cucumber dependencies are part of the jar. It can work in IntelliJ if you mistakenly added it to the classpath instead of adding it to the `pom.xml` file.